# Insert record combined from our and other table data in oracle

Tags: database, oracle

I'm Practicing a lab manual.And there is a question in which i have to insert data provide and some data from other table on the base of provided data.

Like question is.

```
Insert data in EMP_TRAINING:
Employee 3400 gets Developer 6i training and his attendance is 87%.
```

EMP_TRAINING table have columns Empno, Tcode and Attendance.

and in question empno and attendance is given but not Tcode.Developer 6i is the title of Tcode in Training table.so i need to write a query some thing like

```
insert into EMP_TRAINING values(3400,select Tcode from TRAINING where Title='Developer 6i',87)
```

but it's not working.what changes i have to do??

and how it will be in case of multiple records like

```
insert all
into EMP_TRAINING values(3400,select Tcode from TRAINING where Title='Developer 6i',87)
into EMP_TRAINING values(3300,select Tcode from TRAINING where Title='Typing/shorthand',95)
select * from dual;
```

commit;

solved by

```
insert all
into EMP_TRAINING values(3400,(select Tcode from TRAINING where Title='Developer 6i'),87)
into EMP_TRAINING values(3300,(select Tcode from TRAINING where Title='Typing/shorthand'),95)
select * from dual;
commit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `values` keyword while using `Insert into...select` statement.
You will have to specify order of the columns to insert data with `select` statement into `EMP_TRAINING` table.

So, your query should look like this

```
insert into EMP_TRAINING(Empno, Tcode, Attendance)(select 3400, Tcode, 87 from TRAINING where Title='Developer 6i')
```

Comment: is (Empno, Tcode, Attendance) part necessary now?? and remove 87 at the end in query.

Comment: and how it will we applicant able in case of multiple records??? editing the question.